# @Formula field giving syntax error in mysql

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
@Formula(value="SELECT  CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYNAME ,CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYCODE FROM CMS_COUNTRIES WHERE CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYCODE='CNTR0001'")
private CountryMasterModel _tranCountry;
```

The query execute fine in the SQL Editor but gives an error while running the application.

SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYNAME ,CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYCODE FROM CMS_COUNTRIES ' at line 1

Pls provide some of your input.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that this kind of *Formula* must be enclosed in `()`

```
@Formula(value="(SELECT  CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYNAME ,CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYCODE FROM CMS_COUNTRIES WHERE CMS_COUNTRIES.COUNTRYCODE='CNTR0001')")
private CountryMasterModel _tranCountry;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but will the values countryname and countrycode will be set inside the CountryMasterModel. Operand should contain 1 column(s) the error i get

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly the answer is: The *Formula* statement inside of the `()` will/must at the end reperesent exactly **one** column. This is how it was inteneded, as a computed column...